# nervgh/angular-file-upload queueLimit greater than 10

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I used angular-file-upload directive for uploading my images.

```
.value('fileUploaderOptions', {
    url: '/',
    alias: 'file',
    headers: {},
    queue: [],
    progress: 0,
    autoUpload: false,
    removeAfterUpload: false,
    method: 'POST',
    filters: [],
    formData: [],
    queueLimit: 20,
    withCredentials: false
})
```

I want to set the queueLimit.

`queueLimit: 5` works.

`queueLimit: 20` -> max. queue length = 10.

Why?

Does the directive have min and max integers for parameter `queueLimit`?
Actually I want no queue limit, so that the user can upload unfinitely many images.

Answer (score 1):

note that `queueLimit` in the `'fileUploaderOptions'` should be equal to Number.MAX_VALUE:

```
.value('fileUploaderOptions', {
        url: '/',
        alias: 'file',
        headers: {},
        queue: [],
        progress: 0,
        autoUpload: false,
        removeAfterUpload: false,
        method: 'POST',
        filters: [],
        formData: [],
        queueLimit: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        withCredentials: false
    })
```

in order to set the limit of the queue, use `uploder.filters`. example:

```
    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item , options) {
            return this.queue.length < 15; //set the queue length max value
        }
    });
```

> Actually I want no queue limit, so that the user can upload unfinitely
>   many images.
>   set the function to return true always :

```
fn: function(item , options) {
                return true; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solution worked with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423181/nervgh-angular-file-upload-how-to-limit-the-number-of-images-to-upload/25084770#25084770)

in controller

> var uploader = new FileUploader({
>       queueLimit: 1
>   });

then in the view.

> < element nv-file-drop filters="queueLimit">